# If x and y are real numbers and $\sqrt{x^2+2xy+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2-2xy+y^2}=2x$ it cannot be true that...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If x and y are real numbers and...
$$\sqrt{x^2+2xy+y^2}+\sqrt{x^2-2xy+y^2}=2x$$
...it cannot be true that

A) $x\gt y$
B) $x\lt y$
C) $x = y$
D) $x\ge 0$

The answer is is supposed to be B.

After applying the binomial formula on the expressions under the radicals I get...
$$\sqrt{(x + y)^2} + \sqrt{(x - y)^2} = 2x$$
...and if I go a step further simply...
$$x+y+x-y= 2x$$
...but this doesn't really tell me anything, right? So what I tried to do was replace the variables with random small numbers in the PREVIOUS step, like...okay if (as in A) $x\gt y$ then let's use $x=2$ and $y=1$
$$\sqrt{3^2} + \sqrt{1^2} = 3 + 1 = 2*2$$ so, yup, checks out.
let's try option B: $x\lt y$ with $x=1$ and $y=2$
$$\sqrt{3^2} + \sqrt{-1^2} = 3 + 1 \neq 2*1$$

So, I just tried some of the options and happened to stumble on the correct answer.
Now, people, my intuition tells me there has to be a more elegant way to solve this.

One thing I wonder about is also since we can simplify until $x+x= 2x$ why do we have to go back a step? It's...confusing.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{(x-y)^2}$ isn't always $x-y$. What happens, for instance, when $y>x$?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt {(x+y)^2}$ might not be $x+y$.  It depends on the various signs.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly notice that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ for all $a$. By triangle inequality $$2|x| \leq |x+y|+|x-y|=2x\implies x\geq 0$$

Since $|x-y| =|y-x|$ we have again by triangle inequality

$$2y\leq 2|y| \leq |x+y|+|y-x|=2x\implies x\geq y$$

So the answer is $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ (see $-3$, for example).
However it is true that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.